# Grail domain class attribute

Tags: grails

In Grails domain class some one asked this question:

What is required attribute in Grails domain class which is an attribute
that must be specified for every domain class?

Comment: your question is very unclear. please provide more information, otherwise the question will get rapidly down-voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, every attribute you add to a Grails domain class is not-null. The only attribute a domain class is required to have is an attribute that corresponds to the primary key. If you don't declare one yourself, Grails will add:

```
Long id
```

Grails also automatically adds a

```
Long version
```

to each domain class, but you can remove the `version` attribute by specifying the following

```
static mapping = {
    version false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there are any required attributes. 
However I see no point of having a domain class without some kind of property, ie. a String, Integer, int, short ... some other domain instance and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the 'id' ? Though you do not need to explicitly specify that.